# CSS nth-child select all but last element when length is unknown

Tags: css, css-selectors

UPDATE: The fiddle link I posted has the working code now. `:not(:last-child)` and `:nth-last-child(n + 2)` both work perfectly.

I'm trying to use the `nth-child` or `nth-last-child` selector to select every `li` in a `ul` except for the last one. The catch is, the length of the list can vary from 1 to 5 elements. I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples of how to accomplish this.

Here is the HTML for the `ul`:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/categories/1">Articles</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/categories/6">Specials</a>
    </li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="/categories/6/articles/21">Song Lyrics</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my current code:

```
ul > li:nth-last-child(-1n+4) > a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

This code still selects the last element in the list. I've also tried the code below, but that doesn't select anything. I tried a number of other combinations as well, but they either didn't work at all or selected the last element.

```
ul > li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) > a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4q670cf/).

Comment: why not just set a base styling for the `li` and then use `li:last-child` to target the final one only? Shouldn't need 'nth-child' anything to accomplish what you need.

Comment: I'm using Foundation so the styles are mostly defined in a sass file, but this particular aspect isn't a standard option to customize, so I included a custom selector in an overrides sass file.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `:not(:last-child)` to target all except the last.

http://jsfiddle.net/96nd71e3/1/

Comment: Not working even on the fiddle "red" is being ignored.

Comment: The red style is only applied on hover to all row links, except the last. When I hover over the first 4 links, they change to red.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`:nth-last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type) or [`:nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

http://jsfiddle.net/t0k8gp4d/

```css
li:nth-last-of-type(n + 2) a {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/categories/1">Articles</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/categories/6">Specials</a>
    </li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="/categories/6/articles/21">Song Lyrics</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @someuser (he deleted his comment) Unfortunately, that's all I've got.  I understand partially how it works, but I can't give a definitively accurate explanation for it.  The method is [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Summary) with the formula `an+b-1`.  As far as I understand, given that `n` is the index, and adding 2 to that value, the selector starts at 2.  Children are `1` based indexes (not `0` based), and thus, `n + 2` is `0 + 2` resulting in `2` for the first element (second).  adding `last` to the pseudo-class starts it from the end.

Comment: Your method works fine with meterializecss if you have a form within the main nav ( like a search box ), while the proposed doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/categories/1">Articles</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/categories/6">Specials</a>
    </li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="/categories/6/articles/21">Song Lyrics</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul > li{
background:red;
}
ul > li:last-child{
background:black;
}
```

But if you absolutely need to change their style outside of the main li element use this

```
ul > li{
background:black;
}
ul > li:not:last-child{
background:red;
}
```